# How to pretty print in Retrofit 2?

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I have my retrofit set up with `HttpLoggingInterceptor` like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
                .setPrettyPrinting() // Pretty print
                .create();

HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(client)
                .build();
```

On my Gson instance, I did `setPrettyPrinting` and I still get compact JSON outputs.
Here are my libraries.

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
```

How can I acheive pretty printing using Retrofit 2?
Thanks.

EDIT: Updated my libraries and still didn't work

Answer (score 18):

Inspired by Tanapruk's answer this is what I did to make it work with my versions of retrofit (2.1.0) and okhttp.logging-interceptor (3.8.1).

This version works for printing both JSON objects and arrays.

```
class ApiLogger : HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger {
    override fun log(message: String) {
        val logName = "ApiLogger"
        if (message.startsWith("{") || message.startsWith("[")) {
            try {
                val prettyPrintJson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting()
                    .create().toJson(JsonParser().parse(message))
                Log.d(logName, prettyPrintJson)
            } catch (m: JsonSyntaxException) {
                Log.d(logName, message)
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(logName, message)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

And in the client:

```
val httpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor(ApiLogger())
httpLoggingInterceptor.level = Level.BODY
httpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
```

Comment: if JSON is very long it will be truncated, you can log each line one by one like this: ´prettyPrintJson.lines().forEach { Log.d(logName, it) }´

Answer (score 5):

create your own custom HttpLogginInterceptor.

```
public class CustomHttpLogging implements HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger {
    @Override
    public void log(String message) {
        final String logName = "OkHttp";
        if (!message.startsWith("{")) {
            Log.d(logName, message);
            return;
        }
        try {
            String prettyPrintJson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(new JsonParser().parse(message));
            Log.d(logName, prettyPrintJson);
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException m) {
            Log.d(logName, message);
        }
    }
}
```

In your client, add:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new CustomHttpLogging())
            .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Tanapruk Tangphianphan's answer.

I improve it for support all `Java Platform` not only for `Android`.

Create PrettyLogger class

```
class PrettyLogger implements HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger {
    private Gson mGson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    private JsonParser mJsonParser = new JsonParser();

    @Override
    public void log(String message) {
        String trimMessage = message.trim();
        if ((trimMessage.startsWith("{") && trimMessage.endsWith("}"))
                || (trimMessage.startsWith("[") && trimMessage.endsWith("]"))) {
            try {
                String prettyJson = mGson.toJson(mJsonParser.parse(message));
                Platform.get().log(INFO, prettyJson, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Platform.get().log(WARN, message, e);
            }
        } else {
            Platform.get().log(INFO, message, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Use in Buidler:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder();
HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(new PrettyLogger());
loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
builder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin version that doesnot use gson:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor(object : HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger {

    private fun print(m: String) {
        //Crashlytics.log(m)
        Log.i("API", m)
    }

    override fun log(message: String) {
        if (message.length > 500)
            return print("=== more than 500 characters ===")

        if (message.startsWith("{") || message.startsWith("[")) try {
                JSONObject(message).toString(4).also(::print)
            } catch (e: JSONException) { print(message) }
        else print(message)
    }
}).also { it.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY }
```

Answer (score 0):

Beta 2 did not always respect custom gson settings.  Try upgrading to Beta 3.

From the [beta 3 change log](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-200-beta3-2016-01-05) --

> Fix: The Gson converter now respects settings on the supplied Gson
>   instance (such as serializeNulls). This requires Gson 2.4 or newer.

You will also need to upgrade to okhttp3 for beta3.

Comment: Tried with the latest beta4 and it still didn't work.